# Multiply a float with a very large integer in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, largenumber

In Python, is there any way to multiply a float with a very large integer?

As an example, I tried `print (10**100000) * 1.414` 
and it gave me:

`OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float`

Note that the values (the float and that large number) can be anything. More importantly, I want the exact value (rounded to nearest integer) of expression.

Please provide any solution.

Comment: "And more importantly, I wanted the exact value of expression" - then why are you using floats? Floating-point operations are almost always inexact, even the operation of converting the source code characters `1.414` into a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the *exact* value, this means you must have access to `1.414` as a string (otherwise, the value stored in memory isn't exact either).

```
import decimal

float_string = '1.614' # to show that rounding works
exponent = 100000
decimal.getcontext().prec = exponent + 1

c = 10 ** exponent + 1
d = decimal.Decimal(float_string) * c

print d #1614000.....000002
```

Comment: I deleted due to, quoting @Stefan Pochmann, *That's not exact. For example, you get the same value with (Decimal(10 ** 100000) + 1) * Decimal(1.414) but shouldn't.*

Comment: Also, what you did makes it *worse*, as you're changing the value. And it's not clear how you'd turn the float into a string.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'm not sure I understand the first point. Regarding the second point, it seems like OP would have to have access to the value as a string, otherwise 1.414 isn't even stored in memory as an exact value.

Comment: @JaredGoguen I know that 1.414 isn't the exact value of the float. That's the point.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2:**

Ok, I see what you're after:

```
import mpmath

mpmath.mp.dps = 100005
i = int(mpmath.mpf("1.414") * 10 ** 100000)

print(str(i)[:10])        # 1414000000
print(len(str(i)))        # 100001
print(str(i)[-10:])       # 0000000000
print(str(i).count("0"))  # 99997
```

And for @Stefan:

```
int(mpmath.mpf("1.414") * (10 ** 100000 + 1000))
```

returns

```
14140000000000000 ... 000000000001414     # string contains 99993 0s
```

Comment: but mpmath is not a python's native module!

Comment: Your result is wrong, since the float is actually 1.4139999999999999236166559057892300188541412353515625

Comment: @Sushil, you never asked for a python native module.

Comment: Does `1.414 * (mpmath.mpf(10.) ** 100000 + 1)` give the same value or a different value? It should give a different value.

Comment: Yeah, your updated code has enough precision. For **this** case. You hardcoded how much is necessary. Doesn't work in general. Also, you changed one of the values (the float one). The proper setup is like Daniel did it (Setting up two variables `value = 1.414` and `large = 10**100000` and working with those).

Comment: @Stefan *any* code that starts from `value = 1.414` will fail because native Python floats only have 15 digits of accuracy (it's inherent in the IEEE definition of a floating-point number).

Comment: @HughBothwell The problem is *"Multiply a **float** and a very large number in python"*. So we're given a **float**, not a string. And yeah, the float's value in the example isn't 1.414. I know that, as I've shown the exact value above. But so what? Starting with `value = 1.414` is failing. It simply is what it is. And it's exactly the given example. Yours isn't.

Comment: Well, luckily I'm answering Sushil, not you :-)

Comment: @HughBothwell You **might** be answering what Sushil **meant** to ask, but you're not answering what they actually asked.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the float to an integer ratio:

```
value = 1.414
large = 10**100000

a, b = value.as_integer_ratio()
number, residual = divmod(large * a, b)
number += residual*2 >= b
```

Comment: Not giving more accurate value. I tried your code with 10**100

Comment: @SushilVerma Yeah, that proves you wrong. It gives the **exact** value.

Comment: @StefanPochmann at 10^100, it is not giving: OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float.
That is why, I am claiming that  print int((10**100000)*1.414)  is giving correct value. I am not sure.

Comment: @SushilVerma Yeah, so?

Comment: @SushilVerma actually, you are building the product of `1.4139999999999999236166559057892300188541412353515625` with `10000000000000000159028911097599180468360808563945281389781327557747838772170381060813469985856815104.0`. So the question is, what is 10**100?

Comment: @Daniel Those factors are right, but I don't understand your question what 10**100 is.

Comment: I am wondering. Why `print int((10**100)*1.414)`
and `print (10**(100-3))*1414` are printing different values!!

Comment: @SushilVerma That's pretty obvious. You should probably read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

Since you accept integer approximations, here is a native solution:

```
def getint(x, y, z):
    z_nu, z_de = z.as_integer_ratio()
    return ((x**y) * z_nu) // z_de
```

Usage:

```
>>> getint(2, 3, 5.)
40

>>> getint(10, 100000, 1.414)
1413999999999999923616655905789230018854141235351562500000000...  # truncated
```

Comment: That rounds down instead of to nearest integer.